# GitHub Action - AWS CLI

Tags: aws-cli, github-actions

Recently the following GitHub [Action](https://github.com/actions/aws) has been deprecated with a deletion date already established at end of month (2019-12-31). The issue is, there is no "official" alternative yet (should be [here](https://github.com/aws-actions)). My questions are:

1. Does someone know if the "official" action will be released before 2019-12-31?
2. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

aws-cli package is available in GitHub-hosted virtual environments. (aws-cli/1.16.266 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.15.0-1057-azure botocore/1.13.2)

Make sure to set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in environment variables. You can use [Github secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets) to store these credentials securely.

```
- name: Upload to S3
  run: |
    aws s3 sync ./build s3://test-bucket
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'ap-south-1'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the case. If you want it is possible to setup credentials using https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials which is nice if you have to perform more then one step with the aws-cli or have a fancy login schema.

Comment: You don't really need a special step to set up credentials just make sure you name your GitHub repository secrets AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

Answer (score 9):

From [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-software) the `aws-cli` is already available directly on the host image.

It would be nice if this information were available on the deprecation notice
`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: It's not on XL machines yet though

Answer (score 7):

The AWS CLI will come preinstalled on GitHub Actions environments. More information can be found in the [actions/virtual-environments](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md) repository. In my case I needed  the latest possible version of the CLI. I followed the [AWS CLI Install documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) and added the following step to a workflow running on `ubuntu/latest`:

```yaml
-   name: Install AWS CLI v2
    run:  |
          curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o /tmp/awscliv2.zip
          unzip -q /tmp/awscliv2.zip -d /tmp
          rm /tmp/awscliv2.zip
          sudo /tmp/aws/install --update
          rm -rf /tmp/aws/
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to default `awscli`, or using third party actions is to configure python and install the `awscli` at the time of the build:

```
name: Sync to S3 bucket
on: [push]
jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.7'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install awscli
      - run: aws s3 sync builddir s3://foobar --region eu-west-1 --cache-control max-age=0 --acl public-read --delete
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

"Github Actions > Building and testing Python" docs on Github https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python

Comment: FYI, the pip package installs the v1 AWS CLI. From the pypi page:
 "This README is for the AWS CLI version 1. If you are looking for information about the AWS CLI version 2, please visit the v2 branch."
https://pypi.org/project/awscli/

Answer (score 0):

The [repo](https://github.com/actions/aws) was updated yesterday with the following new deprecation notice:

> This action has been deprecated in favor of
>   https://github.com/aws-actions. This repo has been archived and will
>   be made private on 12/31/2019

Comment: The new `aws-actions` does not include de CLI, hence my initial question and followup answer.