How to download a tar.gz from AWS S3 bucket using Terraform
It works for text data, but cant find a way to download tar.gz (binary content) from S3 bucket, Any idea?
data "aws_s3_object" "example" {
  bucket = "some-bucket"
  key    = "someFile.tar.gz"
}

resource "local_file" "downloaded_file" {
  content  = data.aws_s3_object.example.body
  filename = "someFile.tar.gz"
}


it doesn't look like its supported: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_object#attribute-reference

But then is there no other way we can download binary data from an S3 bucket with "pure" TF ?! I Do not want to use " local-exec { with aws s3 cp... "

@tanovsky And is there any particular reason why you don't want to use local-exec?

@MarkoE  aws cli seems to be not available within a terragrunt github action..

Can you try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184490/8343484?
